# update is not happening in table when the row is added(bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a table where I am fetching the data from a json file and giving user the option of add, update and delete along with search option. Every thing is working fine in the table. But it has some bugs like when I add the row in the table and click on update button it doesn't update whereas rest of the update button is working. Other bug is when I search in the search input, I can only search if I enter item name, but I want search item name, place or time. Below is my code so far.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input_style" id="item" placeholder="Enter the Item name">
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
           <input type="text" class="form-control input_style" id="place" placeholder="Enter the Place">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input_style" id="time" placeholder="Enter the time">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-row" value="Add Row"> Add Row</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>Item</th>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var tr;



 //Display table data
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td contenteditable='true'>" + json[i].Item + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td contenteditable='false'>" + json[i].Place + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td contenteditable='false'>" + json[i].Time + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td><div class='edit_button' data-value='Update' value='Update' class='edit'>Update</div>  &nbsp;| &nbsp; <span class='delete' value='Delete' onclick='delete_row(this)'>Delete</span></td>");
    $('.table').append(tr);
}

 //add row in table
  $(".add-row").click(function(){
    var item = $("#item").val();
    var place = $("#place").val();
    var time = $("#time").val();
    var markup = "<tr><td>" + item + "</td><td>" + place + "</td><td>" + time + "</td><td><div class='edit_button' value='Update' class='edit'>Update &nbsp;</div> | &nbsp; <span class='delete' value='Delete' onclick='delete_row(this)'>Delete</span></td></tr>";
    if($('#item, #place, #time').val() == ''){
      alert('Input can not be left blank');
    }else{
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
        $('#item, #place, #time').closest('form').find("input[type=text]").val("");
    }
});

//edit row in the table
$('.edit_button').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('.edit_button').length === 0;
    });
    if ($this.data('value') === 'Update') {
       $this.data('value', 'Save');
       $this.html('Save');
       tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
       tds.focus();
    } else {
       $this.data('value', 'Update');
       $this.html('Update');
       tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
    }

});
});
```

Please can anyone tell me where Iam going wrong?

Comment: the reason that you need to click update to times because `$this.html() === 'Update'` never been true at first time. You can see `$this.html()` have a space at last.

Comment: @QuyTruong I am sorry I din't get. Can you explain? where is the space

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wwsk1mLc/1/ You can test it by yourself.

Comment: Do a search in your code for this -> Update &nbsp;   Testing the value of html for state isn't really the best option.  I would use a data attribute instead.

Comment: @QuyTruong how to fix this I don't want in that way it also doesnt update the row which I add ;(

Comment: @Keith &nbsp; I used for giving space

Comment: @PreetySingh You can use attribute `value` of that div instead: `$this.attr("value") === 'Update'`. https://jsfiddle.net/wwsk1mLc/2/

Comment: And your using this to do your compare too a value without a space, and is the reason I said testing the html content for state is not a good idea.  $this.html() === 'Update'  this does not equal "update &nbsp;"

Comment: @PreetySingh is correct use the attribute, but I would go one further and rename value =  data-value, it's more standard.  Then you can check data-value for state, or even better call it data-state.

Comment: @Keith I am sorry can you give me example I am new to all this. You want me to change data-value?

Comment: @Keith Agree with you. it should be `data-value` then you can use `$this.data('value')`.

Comment: oops just noticed i said PreetySingh is correct, when I meant @QuyTruong :),  But anyway for data attributes have a look here -> https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Yeah!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It worked Thanku :) @Keith Quy Truong but still bug is their. When I click Updated it gives me edit option and text changed to save. It should be like once save is clicked it should show update text again that is not happening

Comment: Then set the text to html, you are doing 2 things here.  1 - Setting the Button Text, and 2 - Setting the button attribute.  Setting the attribute won't change the Button Text..

Comment: Update function is working now. But When I add the row and once it is inserted in the table that particular row doesn't update. I have updated the code.